# Implicit and explicit polynomial surface

Tags: polynomials

An explicit polynomial $R^2\rightarrow R^3$ describes a surface in $R^3$.

E.g. $(u,v) \in R^2, (x,y,z) \in R^3$:
$$\begin{align}
x & = u + v\\
y & = 2u^2-v\\
z & = u-v^2
\end{align}$$
On the other hand there are also implicit polynomials in $R^3$ which describe surfaces in the form $P(x,y,z)=0$, (e.g. $x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2=0$).

My question is: is there an implicit polynomial form for each explicit polynomial $R^2\rightarrow R^3$ which describes the same surface? If so, how can you find it?

Comment: Polynomial implicitization: see Cox, Little, O'Shea, ''Ideals, varieties and algorithms'', page 130.

Comment: If you want a brute-force kind of method, you could consider using [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) with an elimination order to construct a Gröbner basis for $\{x-x(u, v), y-y(u, v), z-z(u, v)\}$.

Comment: With the example you gave, Buchberger's algorithm and an order that eliminates $u$ and $v$ gives us the following: $$4 x^4-4 x^2 y+8 x^2 z-6 x^2-8 x y+8 x z-3 x+y^2+4 y z-3 y+4 z^2+3 z = 0$$